# Silverlight4: navigation wizard

Tags: silverlight-4.0, navigation

I want to make a wizard in Silverlight 4. How to get started?

Let's say I want 4 screens with choices and with a "next" and "previous" button. After the 4 screens, I want to show the "actual" application/mainpage based on the choices the user made in the wizard. On that page there must be an option to return to the first page of the wizard again.

WizardPage1.xaml -> Next -> WizardPage2.xaml -> Next -> WizardPage3.xaml -> Next -> WizardPage4.xaml -> Finish -> MainPage.xaml -> Back to start -> WizardPage1.xaml ->...

Can I use the navigation framework as solution? Users are not allowed to directly navigate to the mainpage.
Or do I have to use a "containerpage" with a contentcontrol for the wizard steps? But how to navigate away from containerpage to the mainpage?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Please do some research on navigation frameworks in Silverlight. There's a lot of information out there - especially on MSDN. Then when you have a specific implementation problem post a question about that.

Comment: I did a demo of 2 Frames on 1 page, it's not exactly what you want but might give you some ideas.  https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/navdemo/src

Answer (score 0):

Refer here http://slwizard.codeplex.com/

Comment: A single link is not an acceptable answer. Can you expand this any?